# Multiple selections in File Upload field; only one is uploading?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form which has an "Upload Field". Once the user finishes the form and clicks "SUBMIT", an email is generated using TCPDF which will send the form in PDF to the user as well as the attachment separately.

The issue is that it doesn't upload all the files I choose for upload. Only the first one I select is uploaded.

Is there any Javascript or PHP code I could insert to force all files to be sent in the email?

---

**EDIT** I saw the form software I'm using does not allow for multiple uploads using their "file upload" function. I will be doing it the normal way. Thanks for your help input I appreciate it.

**EDIT 2** I've sorted the problem out. I'll just be using the multiple file uploads. It isn't that big of a hassle and still looks nice after I've formatted the fields and hidden them based on selection.

Comment: Can you share your code so someone can point your problem.

Comment: I support @OlcayErtaş ... Please share the code in question, and we may be able to provide an answer.

Comment: You need to add `[]` behind your input name. That will make `$_FILE['inputname']` an array which you can loop through.

Comment: Alright thanks guys will share it in a bit.

Comment: I've sorted the problem out :)